# Python loops finding random number

Tags: python, loops

```
import random
n=random.randint(1, 5)
i=int(input("Guess a number from one to ten"))
if i!=1 and i!=2  and i!=3 and i!=4 and i!=5:
    print("ERROR")
elif i<n:
    print("SMALL")
elif n<i:
    print
("BIG")
else:
    print("You're right!")
```

Tried to get a num from 1-5 and 3 tries but only got one

Comment: you need a loop of some kind ... maybe `while i != n`  but that would let you guess forever, so youll need to think of something that might be simillar maybe `for i in range(3)` which would always let you guess 3 times ... even if you got it right the first time ... so you will need to keep thinking on it

Comment: This doesn't address your question, but `if i!=1 and i!=2  and i!=3 and i!=4 and i!=5` would be more commonly written `if i not in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`.

Comment: Another side note: your prompt asks for a number from 1 to 10, but your code is written to test 1 to 5.  A guess of 8 would get `ERROR` even though it follows the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is a `for`-loop using the built-in `range` function.

Make sure to put the `input` function inside the loop to get repeated user input. The `if`-`elif`-`else` structure needs to be indented into the for loop as well.

The use of `_` is just a placeholder for an unneeded value.

```py
import random

n = random.randint(1, 5)

# User has 3 tries to get the right number
for _ in range(3):
    i = int(input("Guess a number from one to ten: "))
    if i not in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5):
        print("ERROR")
    elif i < n:
        print("SMALL")
    elif i > n:
        print("BIG")
    else:
        print("You're right!")
        break
```

By using `break` the loop gets terminated, if the user guessed the correct number before his third try.

Answer (score 0):

> You can try the following code:

```
import random
  n=random.randint(1, 5)
  for _ in range(3):
    i=int(input("Guess a number from one to ten \n"))
    if i > n:
        print("ERROR")
    elif i < n:
        print("SMALL")
    elif n < i:
        print("BIG")
    else:
        print("You're right!")
```

> Or you can try this:

```
 import random
 n=random.randint(1, 5)
  for _ in range(3):
    print("Random number is: ", n) # for testing...
    i=int(input("Guess a number from one to ten \n"))
    if i not in (1,2,3,4,5):
        print("ERROR")
    elif i < n:
        print("SMALL")
    elif n < i:
        print("BIG")
    else:
        print("You're right!")
```

Comment: It's buried at the end, but the OP's question is how to get three tries instead of one.  This doesn't fix that.